# Defining own instance classes

Tags: class, haskell, instance

I struggle with creating own instances for my datatypes. 
I defined a type like:

`data Breakfast = Egg | Sausage Int | Bread Breakfast deriving (Eq, Show)`

and want it to be an instance of the class Ord. I want to compare it by some rules like: A Egg is as good as 2 Sausages etc.

I tried it like this:

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Breakfast) where
 compare (Egg) (Sausage 2) = EQ 
 ...
```

but I get the error: 
 Variable `a` occurs more often than in the instance head. 
i tried another example and this works fine:

```
data Down a = Down a deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

instance Ord a => Ord (Down a) where
 compare (Down x) (Down y) = y `compare` x
```

Hope you guys can help me whats wrong. Im very new to Haskell. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the constraint on your instance definition:

```
instance Ord Breakfast where
  compare (Egg) (Sausage 2) = EQ 
  ...
```

You had a constraint on a type variable `a` which wasn't used on the right-hand side (the instance head).

Comment: ok it works. Thank you. But i thought you had to do this if a class already exists and you want your own type to be a part of the typeclass?

Comment: You have to do it when you need to enforce some constraint on some type variables. For example, in your instance of `Ord (Down a)`, if you were not to have the constraint `Ord a`, you wouldn't be able to use `compare x y` as `x` and `y` are of type `a`.

Comment: Ah thank you. Now it makes sence. One last question if its ok for you. I have `compare (Egg) (Sausage 2) = EQ` and that works fine and now i want another pattern like `compare (Sausage 3) (Egg) = GT` and that get me a parse error on the second " = ". Do you know why?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Check the indentation.

Comment: you are right. It was just a tab or something. Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help